# If conditional that expresses two of what you think will happen

Tags: conditional-constructions

Is it okay? For example you are talking to someone sad, and you want him to wear a happy mask, you'd say

> 1. If you wear this mask, you will seem like you're happy, but you're crying inside.
> 2. If you wear this mask, it will silently kill you, but you'll still choose to hide.

In 1, I expect that he will seem like happy but will still be crying under the mask.

In 2, I expect that the mask will silently kill him eventually figuratively, but I also expect that he'll still choose to hide.

Are these grammatically correct? And did I punctuate them correctly? With commas before buts.

Answer (score 1):

The sentences in quotation marks are grammatically correct, and it is fine to put a comma before the 'but' in those cases. However, the crying part may be unclear. It is fine in informal English, but if you want to make sure people understand that it is part of your prediction, then you might want to say "you'll be crying inside" instead.

There are slight grammatical mistakes in the rest of your post. Also, it is not very clear what you are asking. I hope I guessed right.

Comment: Please reply me those slight grammatical mistakes. I'd like to see them.